# SCP copying a .js from a remote to local

Tags: javascript, bash, scp

I am trying to copy a .js file from a remote machine to my own. I have looked at scp man and looked at some other stack suggestions, but nothing seems to be working out. Here's what I've been typing from my local machine:

```
Users-MacBook-Pro:Programming user$ scp awshost: ~/file.js    
~/Documents/Programming/
scp: .: not a regular file
cp: /Users/user/fibonacci.js: No such file or directory
```

This is my attempt to copy it from the remote machine in console:

```
ubuntu@ip:~$ scp file.js :~/Documents/Programming
cp: cannot create regular file `:~/Documents/Programming': No such file or directory
```

I'm probably making a minute mistake, but anything is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this: scp -r awshost:~/file.js ~/Documents/Programming/

Answer (score 0):

```
scp awshost:~/file.js ~/Documents/Programming/
```

Here I think you should make sure that the home dir in awshost really has a file named file.js. You can have a detailed learning to usage of scp.

Comment: I double checked that file.js is in the home directory on the remote machine. I tried the line you sent me and a few variants. I Still get the same errors. Thank you though.